# Change / Remove ROLE after redirecting USER wordpress / woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, roles

Since a few days.. I'm trying to find the answer to something that maybe for you is very simple to do.. I would like to Change / Modify or Remove the current ROLE from USERS after page redirection. For example: "premium_user" to "subscriber" I already have a plugin that will redirect users automatically after some time. I've been reading the following articles (but I couldn't find an accurate answer to my needs):

[How to redirect to another page after n seconds in wordpress without using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25789377/how-to-redirect-to-another-page-after-n-seconds-in-wordpress-without-using-javas)

[Wordpress - Logout redirection based on role](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37401949/wordpress-logout-redirection-based-on-role)

[Change user role via URL [WordPress]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32081574/change-user-role-via-url-wordpress)

[Creating a function to logout a WordPress user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49193208/creating-a-function-to-logout-a-wordpress-user)

[Wordpress: Change user role conditionally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9181440/wordpress-change-user-role-conditionally)

Thank you for your time and help !

My apologies, but I don't have skills code, I can understand the global notion, but not the details.

If I cannot find the answer I'll create a re-register page for USERS giving them the ROLE that I need. I'm open to all possibilities !

I suppose that the code must call the redirect rule with "if".. the current user / ROLE.. and the remove / modify or replace ROLE code.. I don't know..

*If there is another way or solution to achieve this, for example making users logout automatically and changing or removing the ROLE after that.

*Or simply by creating a button where they can push in order to modify the ROLE.

*Or even better, if there is some way to give Expiration Time to specific ROLES and after some seconds or minutes the ROLE change or will be removed would be great !

I'm open to all possibilities, because I would like to have more control and decision over USERS ROLES.

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Please try something first and then post your codes, referred links and errors.

Comment: hello, thank you for your reply ! I tried everything with my knowledge.. but I don't have programming skills.. I just need a code to modify the user ROLE after url redirecting. Thank you